# Finding a Cartesian product of multiple lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, iterator, lazy

I came up with an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to find a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of multiple `IEnumerable` sets. I was able to achieve lazy enumeration via [`yield return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx), but I didn't think of a way to do it non-recursively. The result ended up being a **recursive lazy enumeration iterator method**, the first of its kind! *At least as far as I've ever written.*

The idea of the problem came from a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963196/words-with-combination-of-letters-from-a-given-set-in-c-sharp/35964426) where a guy had many sets of characters, and wanted to generate a combination of all of them. Now I'm just interested because it's a fun problem!

I'd appreciate **any kind of review**, although here's two specific things I'm most interested in:

1. Can this algorithm can be de-recursed? If so - should it be, and how?
2. Is there some way it could be generalized even more, beyond what I've done?

---

```
public static class MultiCartesianExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<TInput[]> MultiCartesian<TInput>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TInput>> input)
    {
        return input.MultiCartesian(x => x);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TOutput> MultiCartesian<TInput, TOutput>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TInput>> input, Func<TInput[], TOutput> selector)
    {
        // Materializing here to avoid multiple enumerations.
        var inputList = input.ToList();
        var buffer = new TInput[inputList.Count];
        var results = MultiCartesianInner(inputList, buffer, 0);
        var transformed = results.Select(selector);
        return transformed;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TInput[]> MultiCartesianInner<TInput>(IList<IEnumerable<TInput>> input, TInput[] buffer, int depth)
    {
        foreach (var current in input[depth])
        {
            buffer[depth] = current;
            if (depth == buffer.Length - 1)
            {
                // This is to ensure usage safety - the original buffer
                // needs to remain unmodified to ensure a correct sequence.
                var bufferCopy = (TInput[])buffer.Clone();
                yield return bufferCopy;
            }
            else
            {
                // Funky recursion here
                foreach (var a in MultiCartesianInner(input, buffer, depth + 1))
                {
                    yield return a;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var input = new string[]
{
    "AB",
    "123",
    "@#",
};

foreach (var result in input.MultiCartesian(x => new string(x)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

// Results:
// A1@
// A1#
// A2@
// A2#
// A3@
// A3#
// B1@
// B1#
// B2@
// B2#
// B3@
// B3#
```

Comment: Possible bug - IEnumerable doesn't guarantee ordering, so you can't count on "a correct sequence".  Consider `var input = new HashSet<string> {"AB", "123", "@#"};`

Comment: @Comintern Good catch! Although I'd argue that it should be up to the caller to ensure this doesn't happen. If the order doesn't matter - it's *fine* to use a `HashSet`. If it does matter - it's up to the caller to provide an ordered collection.

Comment: Wouldn't the a cartesian product of these sets also include results like `1A@`

Comment: @JohnK No, a Cartesian product consists of only combinations. Take a look at [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4e/Cartesian_Product_qtl1.svg/220px-Cartesian_Product_qtl1.svg.png). Finding the permutations would be very easy one you have the combinations though, with the MoreLinq's `Permutations` method.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis The link to Wikimedia Commons you provided is prone to rusting – the part `/4/4e/` refers to some Commons' internal indices, which are rebuilt from time to time. It's safer to use a stable links to a resource instead, like [https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_Product_qtl1.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cartesian_Product_qtl1.svg).

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed create a cartesian product without recursion. What you need is to use the enumerator.

I used a non-generic enumerator to work with any types.

```
public static IEnumerable Cartesian(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable> items)
{
    var slots = items
       // initialize enumerators
       .Select(x => x.GetEnumerator())
       // get only those that could start in case there is an empty collection
       .Where(x => x.MoveNext())
       .ToArray();

    while (true)
    {
        // yield current values
        yield return slots.Select(x => x.Current);

        // increase enumerators
        foreach (var slot in slots)
        {
            // reset the slot if it couldn't move next
            if (!slot.MoveNext())
            {
                // stop when the last enumerator resets
                if (slot == slots.Last()) { yield break; }
                slot.Reset();
                slot.MoveNext();
                // move to the next enumerator if this reseted
                continue;
            }
            // we could increase the current enumerator without reset so stop here
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var letters = new string[] { "A", "B" };
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var symbols = new[] { "@", "#" };
var empty = new string[] { };

var collections = new IEnumerable[] { letters, numbers, symbols, empty };
collections.Cartesian()
    // this is just for show
   .Select(x => string.Join("", x.Cast<object>()))
   .OrderBy(x => x)
   .Dump(); // linqpad
```

result:

> ```
> A1# 
> A1@ 
> A2# 
> A2@ 
> A3# 
> A3@ 
> B1# 
> B1@ 
> B2# 
> B2@ 
> B3# 
> B3@
> ```

Comment: It could be even [shorter](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140435/95635) :)

Comment: I think the code is missing the Dispose() of the enumerators (`slots[i]`). To be "fully correct" I would then need to be careful about exceptions...

Comment: `collections.Cartesian() // this is just for show .Select` This will never execute as we can not apply extension methods on IEnumerable. It should be `IEnumerable<T>`. Need to Cast it in `object[].. collections.GetCartesian().Cast<object[]>() // this is just for show .Select(x => string.Join("", x.Cast<object>())) .OrderBy(x => x);`

Answer (score 1):

Found this one from a number of years back. Seems short and to the point:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    if (sequences == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

    return sequences.Aggregate(
        emptyProduct,
        (accumulator, sequence) => accumulator.SelectMany(
            accseq => sequence,
            (accseq, item) => accseq.Concat(new[] { item })));
}
```

Comment: example can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423838/cartesian-product-n-x-m-dynamic-array